# Restrict Direction of rotation in Realtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

have a hand of clock which the player once starts rotating (Dragging) CCW until he completes one full rotation. ( Without lifting drag )

I am trying to lock the rotation to only CCW direction while/once the player starts rotating. I got help from the following links : [Detect Direction][1] by @BobBobson108

Here is gif of what is actually happening: [Demo](http://giphy.com/gifs/3o6ozwvQJxLZPCx5Oo)

```
void OnMouseDrag()
 {
     //rotation
     Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
     mousePos.z = 5.23f;        

     Vector3 objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);        
     mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
     mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;
     angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle - 90f));


     hand_vector = transform.up;
     cross_product = Vector3.Cross(ref_vector, hand_vector);
     dot_product = Vector3.Dot(cross_product, transform.forward*-1);
     //Debug.Log("Hand Vector: " + hand_vector);
     //Debug.Log("Ref Vector: " + ref_vector);
     Debug.Log(cross_product);
     Debug.Log(dot_product);
 }
```

I tried to debug the values of the cross product, but the direction of resultant vector seems to be same even when when the player starts backward rotation.

Also the cross product vector changes direction only when the player starts rotation in CW direction from the default position i.e. 12 'o clock.

I have very less experience of working with Quaternions and rotations. Any help will be highly helpful. Thanks !!!

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufbrw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html function to get the value of the angle. You *should* get a positive/negative value depending on the direction.

You could then lock the rotation if the sign is not the correct direction you want.

Comment: I tried. Its the same thing blocking me, the direction of angle between the two vectors DECREASES. The sign only changes when you start rotation in CW from the ref_position i.e 12 o clock.

Comment: Do you use the correct forward/upward vector? You can try visualizing them with the Debug.DrawLine function and see if everything is in order.

Comment: Yes, I am using the transform.up of the hand gameobject which the player is rotating. And at start I am assigning the transform.up to the Reference vector. Hence I am checking for the angle between the two.

Comment: I managed to figure out the solution to the problem. I have posted my answer [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1176039/view.html) incase anyone stumbles across similar issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a solution to above question. Here I am posting my solution in case anyone stumbles across a similar situation in future.

```
void OnMouseDrag()
{

    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0, Mathf.Sqrt(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") + Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"))));  

 /*      
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos.z = 5.23f;

    Vector3 objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
    mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;

    print("Angle is :");
    print(Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f);

    if (counter_clockwise)
    {
        if (Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f > 0)
        {
            angle = Mathf.Max(angle, Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
        }


        if (Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f < 0)
        {
            angle = Mathf.Max(angle, 360 + (Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90));
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
        }
    }            
*/
        glow_color.a = 1f;
        child_yellowglow.color = glow_color;                           
}
```

I am setting the direction bools from using this :

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    Vector3 mouseDragStartPos = Input.mousePosition;

    print("Mouse pos:  " + mouseDragStartPos);
    print(" ref_vector" + ref_vector);

    if (mouseDragStartPos.x < ref_vector.x)
    {
        clockwise = false;
        counter_clockwise = true;
        print("Left !!!");
    }

    if (mouseDragStartPos.x >= ref_vector.x)
    {
        clockwise = true;
        counter_clockwise = false;
        print("Right !!!");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps !!!